# Dynamic web module in Eclipse Mars with M2E unstable config when changing versions in project facets

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, tomcat, m2e

I have a dynamic web module project configured to be a Maven project with M2E. I only use Eclipse's embedded maven to do anything with the project, so no command line cleans etc.

I'm using Tomcat 7 and the first problem I have is that M2E will update the dynamic web module facet to `3.1` when I run `maven->update project...` so that I can then no longer deploy to Tomcat.

I can't downgrade the facet to `3.0`. Eclipse just says something like "Can't do that". However I can deselect the facet, and then `apply`, and then set it to `3.0`.

At that point, I can then deploy the app into tomcat.

However as soon as I run `maven->update project...` again on the project (called for example `Foo`), the project facet is upgraded to `3.1` and it creates a new project called `FooEAR` with the war module in the EAR deployment assembly.

What is badly wrong in my config? (I do not have project facet EAR checked)

[Update] Still getting the weird myprojectEAR project on a non war project.

Eclipse Mars 4.5.1

M2E 1.6.2

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
            http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
    <targetRepositoryId>init later</targetRepositoryId>
    <targetRepositoryUrl>init later</targetRepositoryUrl>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <targetPath>${basedir}/src/main/javadoc</targetPath>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/overview.html</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/thunder</directory>
        <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/thunder</targetPath>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>*</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
              <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <descriptor>src/assembly/zip-file.xml</descriptor>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>ZipOntoNexus</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.zip</file>
              <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
              <artifactId>${project.artifactId}-zip</artifactId>
              <version>${project.version}</version>
              <repositoryId>${targetRepositoryId}</repositoryId>
              <url>${targetRepositoryUrl}</url>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <groups>com.foo.IntegrationTest</groups>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*.class</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>${basedir}/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
          <propertiesLocation>${basedir}/checkstyle/checkstyle-maven.properties</propertiesLocation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <delete failonerror="false">
                  <fileset
                    dir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}"
                    includes="version*.txt" />
                </delete>
                <mkdir
                  dir="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}" />
                <touch
                  file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/version-${project.version}.txt" />
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>debug deploy</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <configuration>
              <tasks if="project.version  SNAPSHOT">
                <property name="targetRepositoryUrl" 
                    value="${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url}" />
                <echo message="url=${targetRepositoryUrl}" />
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <!-- add-test-source goal executed at generate-test-sources phase. -->
        <!-- http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/integration-testing-with-maven/ -->
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-integration-test-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-test-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src/integration-test/java</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
        <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <targetClasses>
            <param>com.foo.*</param>
          </targetClasses>
          <targetTests>
            <param>com.foo.*</param>
          </targetTests>
          <excludedGroups>
            <excludedGroup>com.foo.PitSkip</excludedGroup>
          </excludedGroups>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.fortify.ps.maven.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-sca-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.50</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
          only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.7,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[0.5,)
                    </versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <!-- see http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered -->
                    <ignore></ignore>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.3,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <execute>
                      <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                    </execute>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: @khmarbaise it's there, minus dependencies and reporting sections which i considered irrelevant, for conciseness.

Comment: Why are you executing the maven-jar-plugin within a war project?  And why are you separately using maven-deploy-plugin to deploy a zip file cause this will be done automatically cause you are using the maven-assembly-plugin ?

Comment: Don't know about the maven-jar-plugin, someone else put that in. Hadn't  seen it. But the zip file needs to be deployed via `deploy-file` so that maven will automatically generate a pom for it. If I deploy it with `deploy:deploy`, then it is deployed with the whole pom here, which includes `packaging=war` and that foobars our in-house deployment tool which requires `packaging=zip`. It's not finished either. So essentially this stuff looks ugly, but doesn't have any effect on the issue here.

Comment: You should usually do deploy via `mvn clean deploy` than maven-assembly-plugin will create a zip file which is also deployed to the appropriate repository manager..no need for maven-deploy-plugin in your build manually...Your inhouse tools needs a pom with packaging `zip` Hm..does not really makes sense..The artifacts might be required having a zip extensions yes ok...but the pom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Disable "Dynamic web project" facet.
2. Set servlet version to 3.0 in web.xml:

   > ```
   > <web-app version="3.0" ...
   > ```
3. Set servlet version to [3.0.x](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api) in pom.xml (don't forget "provided" scope):

   > ```
   > <dependency>
   >   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   >   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   >   <version>3.0.1</version>
   >   <scope>provided</scope>
   > </dependency>
   > ```
4. Reenable "Dynamic web project" facet 3.0.
5. Press Alt+F5.

Comment: You are a `legend`. I didn't clock that dependency version - it's set in my parent pom. I'm using annotations so I have no web.xml - I'll just check now that it all works.